# I need to create a view in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a view in the database when two columns are refer from same table. I can create a view like this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[ViewJournal]
AS 
    SELECT 
        J. d, J.date, J.drac, L.name as draccount, J.crac,
        L.name as craccount, J.dramt, J.cramt, J.lf,
        J.description, J.voucherType, J.reg_date, J.last_update,
        J.active 
    FROM 
        Journal J, Ledger L 
    WHERE 
        J.drac = L.Id
```

But the result doesn't not show actual result.

Here, `crac` and `drac` are refered to from `Ledger` table.

`Journal` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Journal] 
(
   [Id]             DECIMAL (18)    IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
   [date]           DATETIME        NULL,
   [drac]           DECIMAL (18)    NULL,
   [crac]           DECIMAL (18)    NULL,
   [dramt]          DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
   [cramt]          DECIMAL (18, 2) NULL,
   [reg_date]       DATETIME        NULL,
   [last_update]    DATETIME        NULL,
   [active]         INT             NULL,
   [lf]             VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
   [description]    NVARCHAR (150)  NULL,
   [voucherType]    VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
   [sales]          VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
   [purchase]       VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
   [cash_paymentno] VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
   [cash_receiptno] VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
   [expense]        VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
   [income]         VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
   [advance]        VARCHAR (50)    NULL,
   [remunaration]   VARCHAR (50)    NULL,

   CONSTRAINT [PK_Journal] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
   CONSTRAINT [FK_Ledger] FOREIGN KEY ([drac]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Ledger] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

`Ledger` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ledger] 
(
    [Id]             DECIMAL (18)  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [name]           NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [type]           NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [classification] VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [realornominal]  VARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [reg_date]       DATETIME      NULL,
    [last_update]    DATETIME      NULL,
    [active]         DECIMAL (2)   NULL,
    [depree]         VARCHAR (50)  NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Ledger] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Does the same query work when it is not in a view?

Comment: Are you getting an exception, or is it simply that the result is not what you were expecting? The only field you're selecting from the `Ledger` table is `name`, and you're grabbing that twice. Is this intentional?

Comment: 6 11/20/2015 12:00:00 AM 6 Sales Account 7 Sales Account 200.00 200.00   Journal 11/20/2015 11:09:33 AM 11/20/2015 11:09:33 AM 1
7 11/20/2015 12:00:00 AM 8 Cash Account 6 Cash Account 200.00 200.00   Journal 11/20/2015 11:24:51 AM 11/20/2015 11:24:51 AM 1

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: i got this answer ...but in their craccount value was same as draccount value.Actually it defferent

Comment: Well then that's because you're selecting `Ledger.name` for both fields: `L.name as draccount, ...,  L.name as craccount`

Comment: Yes,the two values are needed in same table....is any way

Comment: But you're selecting the *same field* twice. `craccount` is never different from `draccount` if they're pointing to *the same field in the same record in the same table* .

Comment: L.name has been selected twice as   `draccount `  and   `craccount ` .

Comment: Is any method to do that......I need to select Same field in ledger but diferent value

Comment: Can you give us more information like the schema of the tables?

Comment: What do you want the value to be? If you type `L.name as draccount, 'Hello' as craccount` then the `draccount` will always be `name` from `Ledger` and `craccount` will always be `Hello`. You can select any information you have in your database. Currently, you're selecting the same information twice.

Comment: L.name drac value "1" and crac value "2" but 1 and 2 are Ledger table Ids

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current query, you're joining on `J.drac = L.Id`, which means that `L` will always be the record which is referenced in `J.drac`, regardless of the value of `J.crac`.

The way I understand it, you want to reference two different records in the `Ledger` table. You need two joins for that.

```
SELECT 
    J.Id, J.date, J.drac, D.name as draccount, J.crac,
    C.name as craccount, J.dramt, J.cramt, J.lf,
    J.description, J.voucherType, J.reg_date, J.last_update,
    J.active 
FROM Journal J
INNER JOIN Ledger D ON J.drac = D.Id
INNER JOIN Ledger C ON J.crac = C.Id
```